# Firestore StreamBuilder ListView - screen flickering

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am working on a screen with nested StreamBuilder tied to two Firestore DB collections. It gets refreshed when the user does an operation on the UI and that intern makes a change in Firestore DB. Every time a DB change happens the screen flickers and moves to the top ignoring the current scroll position. Is there a way to avoid this bad user experience? Thank you.

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: stream1(),
            builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> userOrder){
          return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: stream2(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
            switch(snapshot.connectionState){
              default:
                return new Scaffold(
                    appBar: getHeaderAppBar(),
                    drawer: getLeftMenuBarDrawer(),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    body: Scrollbar(child:ListView(
                      children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot mydoc){           
                        if(userOrder.hasData){
                          ...
                        }
                        ..
                        return ListTile(
                          title: getTitle()
                          subtitle: getSubtitle()
                          isThreeLine: true,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ))}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in my description above. I am not merging the content of two Stream s. Just displaying the content of a single Stream even though I have nested StreamBuilder s. The user acts on the UI => DB changes => StreamBuilder gets updates => UI rebuilt =>Screen jumbs to top after rebuilding of the UI with new data(issue)

Comment: Did you solve it? I work on a chat feature with a single stream from firebase and I have a similar issue, my screen blinks instantly every time I send a message

Comment: Any insights? I'm seeing a blink on a stream-trigger repaint even though the data hasn't changed.

Comment: Any solution for this?. i'm also having this issue...